# Adobe Acrobat Javascript - Can't Export File Attachments

Tags: null, attachment

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro 2020.  I have a very large file (37,121 pages).  It was created by using the Adobe Acrobat Combine feature (close to 8,000 documents).  Once combined, I found there were a lot of file attachments.  The attachments are linked with emails within the document.  When I tried to use javascript's "var d = this.dataObjects," d ended up with a value of null.  I want to export all the attached files to a subdirectory but javascript cannot seem to see them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I need is to copy the files from annotation file attachments to a subdirectory.